# Generic NSOperation subclass loses NSOperation functionality

Tags: generics, swift, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

Today I've met one weird issue when I was trying to 'generalize' my 'CoreData importing operations'.
It appeared that if I create a generic subclass of NSOperation the `main()` func won't be called.

Simple example:

```
class MyOperation<T: NSObject>: NSOperation {

    override func main() {
        println("My operation main was called")
    }
}
```

If you create an instance of this class and add it to the `operationQueue` you will see that it's `main()` isn't actually called.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.operationQueue = NSOperationQueue()
    let operation = MyOperation<NSString>()
    self.operationQueue!.addOperation(operation)
}
```

Operation simply transits from `ready` to `executing` and to `finished` state without calling `main()`.

If I remove generic annotation `<T: NSObject>` from `MyOperation` class it will work fine.

How is this possible?
Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is caused by this simple rule:

> Method in a generic class cannot be represented in Objective-C

As a result, when bridged to Objective-C, `MyOperation` looks like pure, with no methods are overridden, `NSOperation` subclass.

You can see this error by marking `override func main()` with `@objc` attribute.

```
@objc override func main() {  // < [!] Method in a generic class cannot be represented in Objective-C
    println("My operation main was called")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for clarification. It is sad that we cannot use so powerful technique in Swift with Objective-C. In this particular case, 'generalized' operations could help to reuse quite a few bunches of code. Well, yeah. :/

Answer (score 12):

Workaround: You can create NSOperation subclass (no generic), override main and call you own 'execute' func, which can be overriden by generic subclasses.
Example:

```
class SwiftOperation : NSOperation {

    final override func main() {
        execute()
    }

    func execute() {
    }

}

class MyOperation<T> : SwiftOperation {

    override func execute() {
        println("My operation main was called")
    }

}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Very useful also for UIKit delegates!

Comment: I use this method to implement a generic tableViewDataSource

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 7 generic NSOperation has been fixed: if I run this code in a playground it works:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {

    // markup protocol
}

class GenericOperation<SomeTypeImplementingProtocol: SomeProtocol>: NSOperation {

    let referenceToSomeTypeImplementingProtocol: SomeTypeImplementingProtocol

    init(referenceToSomeTypeImplementingProtocol: SomeTypeImplementingProtocol) {

        self.referenceToSomeTypeImplementingProtocol = referenceToSomeTypeImplementingProtocol
    }

    override func main() {

        debugPrint("The GenericOperation main() method was called.")

    }
}

class TypeImplementingSomeProtocol: SomeProtocol {


    init() {

    }
}


let operationQueue = NSOperationQueue()

let typeImplementingSomeProtocolInstance = TypeImplementingSomeProtocol()


let operation = GenericOperation<TypeImplementingSomeProtocol>(referenceToSomeTypeImplementingProtocol: typeImplementingSomeProtocolInstance)


operationQueue.addOperation(operation)
```