# Swift Generic class as delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, generics, swift, delegates

I encountered a problem when using a generic class in swift as a delegate. for example i tried to use a generic NSFetchedResultsDelegate defined as:

```
class FetchedTableController<T:NSManagedObject> : NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate
```

Inside the class i setup a NSFetchedResultsController and set the delegate to 'self'. But for some reason the delegate methods never got called. When i removed the Generic part of the class, the delegates got called as expected:

```
class FetchedTableController : NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate
```

Is there a solution to use generic classes as delegate?

Comment: What happens if you try FetchedTableController : GFetchedTableController<T:NSManagedObject>, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate?

Comment: see: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26097581/generic-nsoperation-subclass-loses-nsoperation-functionality/26104946#26104946)

Comment: ok do its not possible... i did a workaround creating a second private class to receive the delegate calls. @rintaro Thanks for marking out the answer

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be fixed at Xcode7. I can successfully use generic class as NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UITableViewControllerDelegate etc. ... You don't even need to add the @objc prefix to the class.

However, the class has to still have some NSObject superclass.