# Non-generic Swift class can implement UIPickerViewDataSource but Generic version can't

Tags: xcode, swift, protocols, generics

Swift 1.2 / Xcode 6.3.

Why is this valid:

```
class RangeDelegateNongeneric: NSObject, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    var values = [Int]()

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return values.count
    }
}
```

but this isn't:

```
class RangeDelegateGeneric<T>: NSObject, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    var values = [T]()

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return values.count
    }
}
```

Error: `Type RangeDelegateGeneric<T> does not conform to protocol UIPickerViewDataSource`

Even more oddly, the Fix-it message: `Candidate is not @objc, but protocol requires it` prepends `@objc` to the beginning of each function, but that doesn't Fix-it, and the Fix-it tool is happy to repeatedly prepend `@objc`!

Comment: On which line you get this error? I copied the generic class into my playground and it seems to compile fine.

Comment: Generic classes *cannot* be delegates for Foundation methods, see for example this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26104946/1187415.

Comment: Thanks. In practice this gives me what I need to know. While the compiler's error message is clear proof, if you can point to where in the Apple Tech Docs this is explained, I am happy to credit you with an answer. I was frustrated in that I couldn't find this fact clearly stated in any spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in Swift 2.0, specifically tested in Xcode 7 (beta 5 as of this writing).

99% sure this blog fragment explains it, although a more compiler-nerd-friendly explicit spec statement is bizarrely difficult to find:

https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=29

[Emphasis mine]

> Swift-er SDKs: Swift 2 works even better with the Apple SDKs, thanks
>   in part to two new features in Objective-C: nullability annotations
>   and **generics**. The SDKs have been updated to annotate API that cannot
>   return nil so you don’t need to use optionals as often. And with a
>   **true generics system employed by the SDKs** you can more often preserve
>   detailed type information in your Swift 2 code.