# Swift Generic Class implementing an Objective-C Protocol

Tags: objective-c, swift

My intention is to create a generic class in Swift which conforms to an Objective-C protocol:

The class is:

```
class BaseViewFactoryImpl<T> : NSObject, BaseView {
  func getNativeInstance() -> AnyObject {
    return String("fsd")
  }
}
```

The protocol `BaseView` is:

```
@protocol BaseView < NSObject >

- (id)getNativeInstance;

@end
```

The compiler tells me:

```
Type 'BaseViewFactoryImpl<T>' does not conform to protocol 'BaseView'
```

If I delete `<T>` then there is no error.

What is wrong here? How can I get the correct generic class implementation?

Comment: It's just not possible with generic classes, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26097581/generic-nsoperation-subclass-loses-nsoperation-functionality for a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

//BaseViewFactory.swift

```
class BaseViewFactoryImpl<T> : NSObject, BaseView {
    func getNativeInstance() -> AnyObject {
        return String("fsd")
    }
```

//BaseViewProtocol.h

```
@protocol BaseView <NSObject>

- (id)getNativeInstance;

@end
```

//BridgingHeader.h

```
#import "BaseClassProtocol.h"
```

Your code should work. Have you created the bridging header to import the obj-C protocol file?

Answer (score 1):

[Starting with Swift 3](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=39), you need to use `Any`, not `AnyObject`, to represent generic `id` values coming from Objective-C.

This builds with no errors:

```swift
class BaseViewFactoryImpl<T> : NSObject, BaseView {
  func getNativeInstance() -> Any {
    return "fsd"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new generic view model, when you try to create any subclass of the generic view model, you need to declare the subclass as a generic class as well. It's kind of annoy.

For a better way, you can use typealias to declare the instance's type instead of using generic:

```
protocol BaseView {
    typealias T
    func getNativeInstance() -> T!
}

class StringViewModel : BaseView {

    typealias T = String

    func getNativeInstance() -> String! {
        return T()
    }

}
```